# What does the phrase "whole effect" mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context

What does the phrase "whole effect" mean in this sentence?

"Note, there are no prices on this landing page. The whole effect is one of AO.com's knowledge of its (somehow now desirable) subject".
https://econsultancy.com/blog/67214-email-marketing-finding-the-perfect-blend-of-content-product

I Googled it and found the phrase "full effect".There is also another definition that I found - "useful effect". But this didn't help to understand the idea of the sentence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the linked page, I believe it merely refers to the *cumulative effect of the entire webpage*, that is to say the effect it has on a reader when taken altogether.

The author of the article is trying to impart that this AO.com website's priority in its entire page is not to flout prices but rather knowledge about its subject, whatever that may be.